# Why bootstrap select not working properly

Tags: bootstrap-select

> plnkr.co/edit/66oHtYqc66BBZQWua5el?p=preview
>
> you can see in the link that its aint working and mark icon is not
>   showing too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to create a bootstrap multiple select box.

If so, the reason you may be running into issues is because the current class you are using (selectPicker) would be incorrect.  Your code should look like this:

```
<select multiple id="selectpicker" class="form-control">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
</select>
```

So instead of using the class to target with jQuery, as I believe you are trying to do, use the id value instead.  `$('#selectpicker')`

**UPDATE:**

I tried using the files you were linking to, but couldn't get them to work (not sure what the issue there was).  So instead, I used the cdn links and it seems to be working great now.

Here's a link to the working version: http://plnkr.co/edit/IIvTMLACZHXvhsbRXrkD?p=preview

Comment: i am trying to use bootstrap-select, silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: Please see the working version in the edited answer above.  This is an excellent plugin.  I'll have to use it in future projects : )